# iphone Orientation issue..

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I am getting an issue regarding to iphone screen orientation. My application's base sdk is ios 6.0, deployment target is 4.3 and running on ios 5.0 and 5.1

In application's plist file I set `Portrait (bottom home button)`, `Landscape (left home button)` and `Landscape (right home button)`. I am developing an Universal app. So in every view's `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` method I am conditionally returning `portrait` for iphone and both `landscape` for ipad.

My navigation flow is :

An `UINavigatinController` pushing `UITableViewControler` first tab have `UINavigationController` pusing 2 views one by one on the `rootViewController`.

In my last viewController's `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` method I returned `YES`. But the app this view is not being rotate at all. Not even calling `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` method. :(

My requirement is to support both landscape and portrait orientation to only one viewController not to whole app.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this Orientation Issue by this code in View Controller Class.

```
#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

       return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}
#endif

#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

       return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
       return (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); //IOS_5
}
#endif
```

You have to define this code in .pch file.

Code :

```
 #define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 6.0)
 #define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0)
```

Hopefully, It works.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is after `shouldAutoratate....` being called and I return my desire orientation but app is not getting in that orientation :(

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 6, use `supportedInterfaceOrientations` & `shouldAutorotate` instead of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; (Check for device type here and return appropriate orientations)
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply, but app is not only for ios6. as I mentioned I am running app in ios5 as well

Answer (score 0):

How many UIViewController do you have? Maybe a 2, 3 or more.

Try at each viewcontroller add a code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
NSLog(@"viewcontroller: %@", self);
return YES;
}
```

and you will know, which view controller takes a rotate notification. It seems problem im Modal view controller.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is after `shouldAutoratate....` being called and I return my desire orientation but app is not getting in that orientation :(

Comment: this is iOS 6 problem. For this look at this http://grembe.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/here-is-what-i/

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)

  // setFrames=CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is after `shouldAutoratate....` being called and I return my desire orientation but app is not getting in that orientation :(

Answer (score 0):

You should implement all these methods to make it work for all the devices having ios >= 4.3 version..

```
// Autorotation (iOS <= 5.x)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ;
}


// Autorotation (iOS >= 6.0)

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is after `shouldAutoratate....` being called and I return my desire orientation but app is not getting in that orientation :(